# How to submit a dynamically created form using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Submit is not working form me, please can anyone can solve this ?

```
$(function(){
    $('#postImg').click(function() {

        var form = $("<form/>", {
            action: "checkout.php",
            method: "POST"
        });

        form.on("submit");
        $.each(['tprice', 'tevents'], function(i, v) {
            $("<input/>", {
                type: "hidden",
                name: v,
                value: $("#" + v).text()
            }).appendTo(form);
        });
        form.submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you need to insert it into the DOM first.

Comment: So i can use like this form.appendTo('body')[0].submit();

Comment: Is there any other easy way to submit this ??

Comment: Well, you can use `form.appendTo('body').submit()` (without a given argument, the jQuery `submit` method behave similarly to the native `submit()` method).

Comment: I'm able to submit the form without appending it to the DOM, if I remove the redundant `.on` call.

Comment: Isn't `form.on("submit");` an error? It should be `form.on("submit", handler);`.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing here is trying to make an HTTP POST request in a really roundabout way (creating a form just for the purpose, populating it, posting, and then discarding).

It would be much easier and less confusing to directly use [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead.

For example:

```
var parameters = {
    'tprice': $("#tprice").text(),
    'tevents': $("#tevents").text()
};
$.post("checkout.php", parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to post a form that's not being bound into the DOM ? Maybe

```
$.post("checkout.php", { paramName: "value", paramName2: "value2" } );
```

is what you need ?